# Drain Node at Shutdown

Tags: kubernetes, openshift

I want to drain node on shutdown and uncordon on start, I wrote below unit file but i am getting error (Openshift 3.11 and Kubernetes 1.11.0)

```
[Unit]
Description=Drain Node at Shutdown
DefaultDependencies=no
Before=shutdown.target reboot.target halt.target
[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/bin/sleep 60 && kubectl uncordon $HOSTNAME
ExecStop=kubectl drain $HOSTNAME --ignore-daemonsets --force --grace-period=30  && /bin/sleep 60
[Install]
WantedBy=halt.target reboot.target shutdown.target
```

its giving me error

```
error: no configuration has been provided
```

I set Environment variable but still no success

```
[Service]
Environment="KUBECONFIG=$HOME/.kube/config"
```

Comment: What user does the Unit run as? Confirm that this user indeed has a `~/.kube/config` file, as it seems that this is not the case

Comment: @Simon Thanks for comments, $HOME was not working so i have to mention complete path for config in "Environment"

Answer (score 1):

Following systemd unit is working, in ExecStop %H should be use for HOSTNAME

```
[Unit]
Description=Drain Node at Shutdown
After=network.target glusterd.service
[Service]
Type=oneshot
Environment="KUBECONFIG=/root/.kube/config"
ExecStart=/bin/true
ExecStop=/usr/bin/kubectl drain %H --ignore-daemonsets --force --grace-period=30 --delete-local-data
TimeoutStopSec=200
# This service shall be considered active after start
RemainAfterExit=yes
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```